# What is the problem with this regex? Suffix from smatch is always empty

Tags: c++, regex

I have this regex

```
int main ()
{
    const std::string rna = "Feb 11 16:55:35.127897 oms1_OMSController Data: <RBC rbcID=9001><ChannelStates rbcTimeStamp=20200211152135Z><channelStateList><CS channelID=RCS0-OMS-Diag available=no/></channelStateList></ChannelStates></RBC>" ;
    const boost::regex re( "^([[:alpha:]]{3})[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+) ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})(\\.[0-9]{6})? ([[:alnum:]_\\.]*) (([[:alpha:]]{3})[[:space:]]+([[:digit:]]+) ([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})(\\.[0-9]{6})? ([[:alnum:]_\\.]*))?.*.*?" ) ;

    boost::smatch match ;
    if( boost::regex_search( rna, match, re ) )
    {
        std::cout << "SUFFIX " << match.suffix().str() << std::endl;
        for(auto i = match.begin(); i != match.end(); i++)
            std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can help me to understand why my suffix is ​​always empty ?  If i remove `.*.*?` from the end of regex the suffix will be ok. What does mean `.*.*?` ?
I also know `.` means any character and `*` means 0 or more.

Comment: In most regex engines `.*?` means a non-greedy match, meaning grab the least amount from this pattern to at least match it. Having that prefixed by `.*` is a bit weird.

Comment: Have you tried [debugging your regex](https://regex101.com/r/vrifu6/1)?

Comment: What do expect? `match.suffix().str()` returns a _character sequence from the end of the match found to the end of the string being matched or searched_. `.*` will match everything so the end of the match and the end of the string are the same.